# Empty textBox (null; string.IsNullOrEmpty) Issue in TextChanged

Tags: c#, string, null, windows-phone, textchanged

I have a problem when checking if a textBox is empty.
I have read many questions and answers here, and I have used the codes mentioned but with no luck.

I just want to check if a textBox is empty, and if it is then do something, if not, do something else.

So far I have tried the following codes:

```
(textBox4 != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))
(textBox4.Text == "")
(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.text)
(textBox4.Text != Stirng.Empty)
(textBox4.Text.Trim() == "")
(textbox4.Text.Length == 0)
```

None of the codes show any errors, but they still do not work.
Here is my complete code for what I am trying to do:

```
     private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
   {
    try
        {
            double a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox10.Text);                
            double c = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            double d = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            double ee = Convert.ToDouble((0.13 * d) * 2);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))
            {
                textBox15.Text = Math.Round((((((ee / 2) / c) * 0.13) + (d * 0.13)), 4).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                textBox15.Text = (((((a / 2) / c) * 0.13) + (d * 0.13)) / b).ToString(); 
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

(textBox 3,10,15 are IsReadOnly="True", and the Keyboard is InputScope="Number", if that matters)

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I have tested every code there is, and I don't understand why it doesn't check if the textBox4 is empty.

**EDIT**:
When I write something in textBox4, the code works, and when I delete the entry from textBox4 it detects that the textBox4 is empty (but that's late)

**EDIT 2**:
This same If/Else code for textBox15 is written under the TextChanged events for all of the other textBoxes involved (1,2,3,4,10,15).

When I put a Breakpoint on the If and Else statements, it gets executed only when:

- The code works for the If statement only when I type something in textBox4 and then delete it.
- It works for Else statement only when I type something, then delete it, and then retype it again.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the debugger.  What is the value of textBox4.Text when these conditions are failing?

Comment: Are you creating `textBox4` dynamically, if not then you do not need `textBox4 != null`.

Comment: textBox4 stays empty until the user fill something in. It is a calculator, so everything is filled with numbers. When the textBox4 is emtpy, it needs to execute the first If statement, but when the user enters something in the textBox4 it need to execute the second Else statement

Comment: You want the fist statement to run if `textBox4` is blank, then `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))` should do. `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text)` means the textbox is not empty.

Comment: @unlimit No, the textBox4 is already created. I have tried to use the code without 'textBox4 != null', but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure nothing is working? Some of your tests test for an empty box, others test for the _opposite_, so if you just replace your if-condition, you get different results...
And Bolu has a good point, can you please tell us _what_ is going wrong? Does textBox15 stay empty? Because in that case the problem i snot with your if-statement.

Comment: @unlimit, thank you, i have changed it now to `(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have solved my own problem by using **string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace** Method.

> "I just want to check if a textBox is empty, and if it is then do something, if not, do something else."

Here is how the code worked:

```
  private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)

try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox4.Text))
            {
                //do something
            }
        }

        catch
        {
        }
```

Thank you all for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text.Trim())?`

That should help you to remove any spaces that might still be lingering in the text box.

Answer (score 1):

"it somehow doesn't detect that the textBox4 is empty, and nothing happens. When i fill in the textBox4 with some value the code works. "

So am i correct in understanding that you expect to run this code and for the "textBox4_TextChanged" method to be called? Because that looks like an event handler that will be called only when textBox4 *changes*

So indeed, not yuor if statement is the problem, your whole method is not being called initially.

What happens if you fill in something in textBox4 and then delete it so it *changes* to empty?
I would dare to bet that your code works then.

So you want to *initialize* your textBox15 value correctly :)

Simply assign the correct value (for when textBox4 is empty) to textBox15 when your program is starting up :) This can be in the constructor of your form, or when you create textBox15, I don't know how you have set up the rest of your project.

An extra tip: using the debugger and setting a breakpoint on your if statement, you would have noticed that your code is never getting executed *until* you actually *change* the value of textBox4. 
(Although the name of the method should also have been a hint ;) )

Comment: Yes, you are right. When i enter a value, and then delete it, the code works. :) I am sorry, i am a noob, and i am trying to explain everything as much as i can.

Comment: I didn't initialize textBox15. Could you help me do this? How should i do this?

Comment: @Oerkelens Don't you think just reversing the `IsNullOrEmpty` method will do ?

Comment: @SurajSingh Nopes, I think we have already established that the whole method never gets called initially, which explain why the textBox stays empty.

Comment: @Oerkelens I've tried to write the code under InitializeComponent(); but it doesn't work. I must be writing it wrong. What should i write under InitializeComponent(); in order for it to work. I've tried using the same code as in textBox4_TextChanged that I've mentioned above, and also textBox4.Text = "". ?

Comment: btw. my code for textBox15_TextChanged is the same as the one for textBox4_TextChanged

Comment: whenever your textbox15 is created, add `textBox15.Text = ((((((a / b) + c) * b) * 0.0025) + (d * 0.0025)) / b).ToString(); ` which is the line that shoul dbe executed when box4 is empty.
Also, try putting a breakpoint on that line, and when you press F5, see if it actually gets executed. :)

Comment: @ Oerkelens. Hey thank you for the tip. I've been using now breakpoint, and i can now see exactly when an event is being executed or not. I did what you said, and i have initialized textBox15 now. But the problem is still here. I can see clearly now that the code doesn't get executed even though textBox4 is empty. The only time it works is when i put some value into textBox4 and then delete it. I've tried using different events because i thought that textChanged event was the problem. Every event that I've tried to use so far will work Only when i put a value into textBox4 and then delete it.

Comment: I don't understand why is this happening. Also, i have tried setting a value for textBox4 on loading to be " textBox4.Text = string.Empty; ", to make sure that it actually is empty, but this is not helping as well.

Comment: Is there a value in textBox15, _any_ value, when you start your application? Because if there is not, you have not initiliazed you textbox15 :) That has _nothing_ to do with any textbox4 events that happen or not :)

Comment: When i first start the application, there are no values in textBox15. But there should be no value inside on application start, not until i fill in values in the other textBoxes(1&2). Once the other textBoxes are filled with values, it's then when the value of textBox15 is calculated and should be shown.

Comment: Then you should fill textbox15 in the eventhandlers of textbox(1&2)!
Actually, you can make a private method FillTextBox15 which yuo can call when textbox 1, 2 or 4 changes, _AND_ at application start. Include in that the logic to leave 15 empty if 1 and 2 are not filled.

Comment: I've done that :) Only i haven't written a private method FillTextBox15 so that i can call it. Instead I've written the code under the eventhandlers of every textbox involved(1&2,3,4,10,15). I haven't tried to include the logic to leave 15 empty if 1&2 are not filled. I'll try that now. Also I will edit and update my question so that it can be more clear. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If it start to handle TextChanged event, that mean your `textBox4` is not empty any more, because you've entered something in `textBox4`. Even though all you entered was whitespace, it will still invoke the textBox4_TextChanged method.

So I think you shouldn't put the textBox4 checking line in `textBox4_TextChanged` method.

Comment: Should i use another method? Where should i put the checking line for `textBox4`?

Comment: You should put the checking with if-else code in other TextChanged event handler of textBoxes which are not readOnly, such as textBox1 and textBox2. But for textBox4_TextChanged you don't need to have **if** scope, just put the calculation in **each** scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you jump into the event-handler Textbox4 can't be null. So I would suggest using

```
"if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(TextBox4.Text))"
```

As others mentioned just use a debugger. Usually works nice in Winforms using F5.

If you are absolutely sure there can't be anything in that textbox and the condition still does not work, check your designer-file if the textbox4_TextChanged REALLY is assigned to TextBox4.

But I repeat: Simply use a debugger to look what happens there stepping through the code with F10

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why your 
`(textBox4 != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))`   not working however, while using IsNullOrEmpty you do not need to check null like you did there.
Try to put your value to a string then check for  null or empty.

**Update** : After reading your comment i think you need to reverse your if condition ,
 When a user enters something you need to execute else condition, So when you enter something into textbox4 then on `textBox4_TextChanged` event textbox4 is not empty, So you just need to check your business logic or change your condition .

```
string strtxt4 = Convert.toString(textBox4.text);

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strtxt4 ))
        {
            textBox15.Text = Math.Round(((((((ee / b) + c) * b) * 0.0025) + (d * 0.0025)) / b), 4).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            textBox15.Text = ((((((a / b) + c) * b) * 0.0025) + (d * 0.0025)) / b).ToString(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Validating Event.
I have tried for the same and i think that worked well according to my opinion.
Keep the logic same but write the code in validating event.
If i am wrong please inform me.